# npm-cron issue with task.stop() from inside another function

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, cron, local-node-modules

npm-cron started from inside a function. But can't stop like, from inside a function. the running continues for infinity.

I have to run it in a certain condition until another condition is met. Whenever another condition is happening, I have to stop running.

And also restart the process from somewhere else.

The start is done. Cron Stop is not working.

```
const { log } = require('console');
const cron = require('node-cron');
let i = 0;

console.log("Hello World");
const task = cron.schedule('* * * * * *', () => {
  _find();
  task.stop();
  console.log('running a task every 1 second');
},{
  scheduled: false
});;

function _find() {
  i++;
  console.log(i);
  _checking(i);
}

function _checking(i) {
  if(i===0){
    console.log('started')
  task.start();
  }
  else if (i > 3) {
    console.log('yes');
    task.stop();
    console.log('stopped');
  } else {
    console.log('no');
  }
}
_checking(i);
```